# RooWebJson and KendoUI Grid

Tags: json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, spring-roo, flexjson

I made KENDOUI GRID work for READ with Spring ROO json as the backend.

However, for CREATE the generated response is HTTPSTATUS.CREATED.

KENDOUI GRID is expecting a HTTPSTATUS.OK with response body of "null".

I verified this by pushing-in the roo generated code and made the changes below. It worked.

**JSON.aj Code**

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

**PUSHED-IN Code**

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("null", headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

**Questions :**

Is there a way to change the default response of roo's json aj files?

**Or**

Is there a way to handle other HTTPSTATUS in KENDOUI so a response of HttpStatus.CREATED would be treated as a success.

Lastly, KENODUI GRID seems not to be able to detect when the server encountered errors, since even Error 500 is not caught.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About Roo question the answer is no, you must push-in and customize as needed.

Please, open an improvement issue at https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO

Answer (score 0):

The create response should contain that created record with its ID updated - if you do not return it then the Grid will continue to send the record to the server for creation.

Regarding the error 500 code - the **error** event of the **dataSource** should be triggered and it should contain the response itself so you can notify the user what did go wrong.