# Spring-Roo Push In via Command Line

Tags: json, spring-roo

I need to perform push-ins for my json controllers, however, doing it via STS will make it really tedious. For my demo project, it works since it only contains 10 pojos, but for real world project this may become 20-50 pojos.

Is there a way to perform push-ins via command line or any way to automate it?

I am asking due to my previous issue which cannot be solved by spring-roo's current version :

[RooWebJson and KendoUI Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931604/roowebjson-and-kendoui-grid)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to push-in code via command line. The best way is to use STS, but note you will push-in the code only one time.

Comment: this appears to be the current answer, but it's lame, supporting this through roo commands would make it so much easier to rebuild a roo application

Comment: Please, create a new issue at https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO to take your suggestion in accout